# Case in the query gives undefined property error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use CASE in my query. I have  to calculate the difference between required_number and vehicle_quantity. If it is less than or equal to 0 then I need value 0 otherwise the difference value. I am trying following code directly in  phpmyadmin. But I am getting error:

```
Notice in ./libraries/sql-parser/src/Utils/Query.php#427
 Undefined property: SqlParser\Components\CaseExpression::$expr
```

This is the query I have tried so far.

```
SELECT
    required_number,
    vehicle_quantity,
    CASE
WHEN (
    required_number - vehicle_quantity
) <= 0 THEN
    '0'
ELSE
    (
        required_number - vehicle_quantity
    )
END AS income_amt
FROM
    vehicles
WHERE
    id = 22
```

Can anybody help me what mistake I did in my query. Thank You.

Comment: Note: Use `0` instead of `'0'` as result of your first case ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT required_number,
       vehicle_quantity,
       (CASE
            WHEN ((required_number - vehicle_quantity) <=0) THEN 0
            ELSE (required_number - vehicle_quantity)
        END) AS extra
FROM vehicles
WHERE mun_id=22
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now, I was missing '('

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS:** you have to use `0` instead of `'0'` because you are doing integer based calculation so you can't define string instead

```
SELECT
    required_number,
    vehicle_quantity,
    CASE WHEN (required_number - vehicle_quantity) <= 0 THEN 
        0 
    ELSE 
        (required_number - vehicle_quantity) 
    END AS income_amt
FROM vehicles
WHERE id = 22
```